# Assign php variable value based on anchor/element clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

So currently, I have three `div`s sliding horizontally to each other. Each div is on full width. My mark up is something like this:

```
<div id="menu">
    <a href="#block1">Go to block 1</a>
    <a href="#block2">Go to block 2</a>
</div>

<div id="block1">
    <?php
        $page = 'block1';
        //code to display corresponding content for block 1
    ?>
    <a href="#menu">Go back to menu</a>
</div>

<div id="block2">
    <?php
        $page = 'block2';
        //code to display corresponding content for block 2
    ?>
    <a href="#menu">Go back to menu</a>
</div>
```

With my current slider purely based on this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/wtvaJ/2/ - what happens is that from the menu, when you click the link to go to block 2, it would slide through block 1 first before block 2.

Now this is supposedly okay, but the content for this will be expanding soon and I'm worried that when the block `div` count is more than four, it wouldn't look nice to slide through all three blocks first before arriving to block 4.

What I thought was something that would just get the value of the anchor clicked and change my markup to something like this:

```
<div id="menu">
    <a href="#block1">Go to block 1</a>
    <a href="#block2">Go to block 2</a>
</div>

<div id="block1">
    <?php
        switch ($page) {
            case 'block1':
                //code to display corresponding content for block 1
                break;
            case 'block2':
                //code to display corresponding content for block 2
                break;
        }
    ?>
    <a href="#menu">Go back to menu</a>
</div>
```

I also thought about changing the anchor to buttons to pass on the variable like this perhaps

```
<input type="button" value="block1" onClick="javascript:location.href = '#block1'" />
```

But of course, that redirects to the page itself (`#block1`) and not slide like when anchors are used

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Did it satisfy your requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wtvaJ/81/)

**Changes:**

```
var a = $(this).attr('href');
$('.page').hide();
$(a).toggle('slide');
```

Comment: @Suika, Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes! It is, thank you. Do you mind giving me advice on how I can make the animation smoother?

Comment: You can add $(a).toggle('slow'); to make it smoother while sliding.

Comment: Or even specify miliseconds to control speed of effect. http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_toggle.asp

Comment: Sorry, I tried this on my site and even though I added the `$(a).toggle('slow');` the animation looks weird on full width because it animates from the upper left and enlarges to full page. :/

Comment: Add height: 100%; and min-height: 2000px; to .page as you have added to .simulate to control jurk of scroll. http://jsfiddle.net/wtvaJ/84/

Comment: This is another demo, that might be helpful to you. http://jsfiddle.net/hcmLw/2/light/

Comment: @Suika, Did it satisfy your requirement?

Answer (score 1):

One of the most rapid edits in order to keep the same code and save time is to shorten the animation time keeping clean the slide action:

```
$('.wrapper').animate({marginLeft: margin},50);
```

You can also have a dynamic descrescent animation time like:

```
$('.wrapper').animate({marginLeft: margin},1000/(pagenumber*5));
```

Comment: Not really that familiar with jQuery which makes me dependent on answers (as I'm also in a rush) and this just doesn't change anything :/

Comment: I only changed a row in the fiddle you posted [above](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/wtvaJ/2/) . Shortening the time of the animation you can get an effect similar to what @Parkash Kumar suggests. This way you have control on the time of the animation; instead, using query-ui toggle() not.

Comment: This also looks good on the fiddle but right now I have 10 divs and even though I can set the speed of the animation, it's really a pain in the eyes to look at all the divs sliding through.